# how to monitor a file in java while it is being updated by a shell script

Tags: java, file, shell, concurrency

I have a log file that is going to be updated by a shell script. This shell script has a number of operations and updates the file after each operation, saying the operation has finished. Now, I need to 'listen' on this file from a servlet and send response back to the end user in the same fashion as the logging happens (i.e. operation A finished, operation B finished and so on). Now if both the servlet and the shell script try to open the file at the same time I am sure I will get some error. In java I guess I can handle it as IOException and keep trying to read the file, so that it works when the shell script is not updating the file. How should I handle this in shell script? Will it help if I open the file in read only mode in java? Also note that the shell script only writes and doesn't read and the servlet only reads and doesn't write.

Also, suggestions welcome on a better way of implementing this workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't use the WatchService, you could poll the files last modification using `file.lastModified()`.

If you do this periodically, you can compare the results and if they changed, the file was modified by the shell script. It might be necessary to create a new File object everytime you poll, but since the file isn't opened for reading at all no access problems will occur.

However, even if you open the file and compare its contents you should not experience any access problems, unless your shell opens the file with exclusive access.

Comment: yes I understand I won't have access problems in java because i could open it in read only mode. but suppose I'm trying to read it in java and the script tries to write to it at the same time? wouldn't it throw an error in shell saying something like 'file already open. can't write to it'?

Comment: No, since Java opens the file without locking it. Therefore the shell can open the file for both reading and writing - however if you read the file in Java and the shell writes it the same time, the contents are obviously not consistent. On Unix-based systems there are no file locks at all, these exist only on Windows (and possibly other, rare operating systems). This means neither the shell nor Java can open the file exclusively, thus no errors will be thrown. In any case using `lastModified()` won't open the file at all but only query the filesystem for the modified date.

Comment: thanks a lot for the advice and the lastmodified thing. as for the inconsistency thing i'm not particularly bothered. i'll append some known sequence at the end of each log line and discard lines that miss it while reading it in java. i'll pick them up in the next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Java 7?  If so then maybe the new Watcher service would work for you.  I haven't personally used it but the idea is that you get notifications in your code when a file/folder has changed.  This might make your code cleaner than simply polling a file repeatedly.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html